# YouTube Data API: liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers not returned in response

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Since mid-Jan 2022, I noticed that the YouTube Data API's `list` method no longer returns `liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers`. This happens to me with all live videos in several channels.

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id=[VIDEO_ID]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

Response:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "ETAG_ID",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "ETAG_ID",
      "id": "VIDEO_ID",
      "liveStreamingDetails": {
        "actualStartTime": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ",
        "actualEndTime": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ",
        "scheduledStartTime": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

Document references:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers

From the second doc (bold is mine):

> The property and its value will be present if the broadcast has current viewers and the broadcast owner **has not hidden the viewcount for the video**.

As far as I know, none of the channels nor videos that I tested with have blocked viewcounts.

Is there any other way to retrieve the concurrent viewers programmatically?

Comment: On a currently broadcasting live I don't have your problem. Could you tell me if you are experiencing this issue with currently broadcasting lives and could you provide videoIds which have the bug ?

Comment: I think for ended broadcasts, the "liveStreamingDetails" > "concurrentViewers" becomes the initial value for "statistics" > "viewCount"

Answer (score 0):

"concurrentViewers" is bugged since last month.

Example:

VideoId: 1iw-7ZCVayU

```
TIME        RETURNED CONCURRENT VIEWERS 
09:57PM     26884
09:59PM     26850
**10:00PM       16**
10:01PM     26930
10:02PM     27049
10:03PM     26864
**10:04PM       17**
10:05PM     26987
10:06PM     27154
```

API response includes some incorrect values among correct values. It happens in many broadcasts since last month.

More recent examples:

VideoId: IzbldpY6rYA

```
TIME        RETURNED CONCURRENT VIEWERS 
05:16PM     17534
05:17PM     17570
**05:18PM       12**
05:19PM     17615
05:20PM     17720
05:21PM     18063
**05:22PM       10**
05:23PM     18899
**05:24PM       10**
```

VideoId: Es0W77JUxbk

```
TIME        RETURNED CONCURRENT VIEWERS 
07:30PM     5289
07:31PM     5250
**07:32PM       7**
07:33PM     5265
07:34PM     5192
07:35PM     5119
**07:36PM       6**
07:37PM     5117
```